# Ensembles in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, cross-validation, data-science

I have implemented 4 classifiers using scikit-learn in Python. But, the performance on all of them is not very good. I want to implement an ensemble of these classifiers. I looked up the ensembles on scikit-learn but it has Random Forests and Adaboost. How should I create an ensemble of my weak classifiers?

Comment: Did you look at [VotingClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html)?

Comment: No. I have looked at Adaboost and Random Forests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different ways to create an ensemble using your weak classifiers:

-Bagging: You can average the output of the 4 classifiers.

-Stacking: Your final output could be a linear combination of the 4 individual outputs. You can use the output of your 4 models as the input of a another algorithm or you can directly use different weights by choose the ones with better accuracy.

Comment: Is it fair to assign weights in linear combination according to the accuracy of the individual classifiers?

Comment: You need the output of the classifiers befores deciding 0 or 1 (for example in a linear model output=x*w+b) and you can create a new model whose output is output=w1*output1+w2*output2+w3*output3+w4*output4+b. Then you choose W1,W2,W3,W4 and b using different data from the data used to train the individual models.

Comment: can you tell me how to make this in python , i have six feature subset , for each of them i try multiple classifiers , reach to the most suitable algorithm for each one ... my question now how to combine them using ensemble classifier like bagging, adaboost, voting ,etc